# Linq add a whitespace at the end of self-contained tags

Tags: c#, linq, save, whitespace

I am a newbie and I would like to know if it is normal, when I save an xml file with XDocument linq (ASP.NET c# web page), that a space is added at the end of all self-contained tags.

Here my code:

```
string pathFile = Server.MapPath("\\xmlFolder\\test.xml");
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(pathFile);
xmldoc.Save(pathFile);
```

Original xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre/>
          <price/>
          <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
          <description/>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

xml file after saving:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre />
      <price />
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description />
   </book>
</catalog>
```

as you can see in the elements: genre, price and description a whitespace was added before the closing /

It is normal?

I tried with "SaveOptions.DisableFormatting" but nothing change.

I did a lot of research about it but found nothing
Thank you.

Comment: First question: why do you care?

Comment: The documentation for `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting`  says it will "Preserve all insignificant white space while serializing." - which isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: This is probably done for readability, personally I like that style of a space before the self-close identifier. Both represent a well-formed XML document so there should be no issue parsing this. You can see [examples of both](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) under the section for "Empty Elements"

Comment: White spaces outside the XML tags are ignored according to the XML specification.  The closing tag /> normally has a space.

Comment: ok, from what I understand it's normal behavior.
The problem was raised by the recipients of the activity, I had already pointed out that this did not compromise the fact that the document was well formed.
Thank you all.